# android edittext on api level 19 show unwanted shadow but api above 20 looks fine

Tags: android, textview

[Api level 20](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsyWt.png)Android edittext on api level 19 shows unwanted shadow but api above 20 looks fine. How do I fix this ?

[image]

This is my xml file  .Stucked in this very badly,Thanks in advance.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvHeadLogin"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Login"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/userid" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/input_layout_email"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:hint="@string/hint_name"
                android:textColorHint="@color/colorSecondaryText">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/input_uname"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        <!-- password input -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/password" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/input_layout_passkey"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:hint="@string/hint_pass"
                android:textColorHint="@color/colorSecondaryText">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/input_pasword"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="textPassword" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvForget"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="Forget Password ?"
            android:textColor="#5f44e3" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Login"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Android edittext on api level 19 shows unwanted shadow but api above 20 looks fine. How do I fix this ?

Comment: show your xml code

Comment: edit your question and do copy paste.

Comment: any update of your issue?

Comment: @NiksonKantiPaul  yes just go with the Werner Hanekom's answer ,it work for me. update the gradle build tool.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want any background or shadow at all just apply a background to the EditText.

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/usernameET"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white" <!-- This -->
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/editTextColor"
        android:textColorHint="@color/editTextColor"
        android:textSize="18sp" 
/>
```

Comment: thanks buddy,but i want normal view with underline,as it work on  api 20 good but when i tried it on api 19,it became a mess.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your layout is not rendering properly, I assume things like ripple effects will also have strange boxes etc.

Try updating your gradle build tools to the latest version in your project level build.gradle file.

Change:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:x.x.x'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
```

Could also help to check that all your other dependencies are up to date.